# Webpack configuration that avoids named function calling

Tags: javascript, webpack

I want to trade *disk space* for *no named function calling* in webpack so that I can do language analysis easier.

However webpack'*ing* the following modules,

- index.js `import foo.js; foo()`

  - foo.js `import bar.js; console.log(bar()) console.log(bar()) console.log(bar())`

    - bar.js `return "THIS IS BAR!"`

Results in:

```
function bar() { return "THIS IS BAR!"; }
function foo() {
  console.log(bar());
  console.log(bar());
  console.log(bar());
}
foo();
```

And I want,

```
function foo() {
  console.log((() => { return "THIS IS BAR!" })());
  console.log((() => { return "THIS IS BAR!" })());
  console.log((() => { return "THIS IS BAR!" })());
}
foo();
```

Even while this will increase the space of the bundle. Because I want to avoid function calling.

#### How can I do this?

So far I have tried with several `{ optimization: { ... } }` rules but none of them leads to the desired result.

Comment: What is the motive behind this ? what you want to achieve by this ? as far as i know calling function will not impact your performance

Comment: @CodeManiac I am not really interested in running the *bundle.js*. I am interested in running language analysis (say for example *word count*, or *sentiment analysis*) in the code output.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with the mode production. With current setting. I can see desire output.

// foo.js

```
import bar from './bar'
export default function print() {
    console.log(bar())
    console.log(bar())
    console.log(bar())
}
```

// bar.js

```
export default function bar() {
    return "THIS IS TEST"
}
```

// webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: "production",
  entry: './src/foo.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'foo.bundle.js'
  }
};
```

// Version

> "webpack": "^4.42.0", "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"

// Output

```
([function(e,t,n){"use strict";function r(){console.log("THIS IS TEST"),console.log("THIS IS TEST"),console.log("THIS IS TEST")}n.r(t),n.d(t,"default",(function(){return r}))}]);
```